# 2 finger scrolling in not working on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: touchpad, hp

I use the Hp-ProBook and I've installed ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. At first, everything is working fine but after some time 2 finger scroll automatically stop working and I've no idea why?

If anyone can help me with this please do..

Comment: There is no Ubuntu version 20 or 20.0

Comment: Ubuntu has releases that use the *year* format (they are *snap* only such as Ubuntu Core 20 and are designed to be used *headless* so no screen or keyboard, nor mouse), and products that use the *year.month* format which are available in desktop & server format.  There is no month 0; and a 20 product has no UI as it's intended to be controlled remotely so *finger scroll* makes no sense for a Ubuntu Core 20 product.  Ubuntu Touch you've highlighted is a different product again - for phones hasn't reached an OTA-20 yet I believe

Comment: "2 finger scroll automatically stop working and I've no idea why?"  you can disable/enable it on some machines by tapping the top right corner of the touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

You may have tried this already - but in settings (menu at the top right - click on the little down-arrow), there's a Mouse and Touchpad submenu - check that two-finger scrolling is enabled. [image: Mouse & Touchpad menu]

I hope this helps.

Comment: I can't see TouchPad option in my setting?

Comment: Sorry that didn’t work. The menu I showed was from my laptop - when I did it from my desktop the menu didn’t give any touchpad options so the menu that comes up depends on the hardware installed. I’m sorry I don’t have any other suggestions.

Comment: @iamhimanshu0 Did you get thise sorted? I can't see that in Settings either ;(

Comment: there is no way we can make it good, i've tried so many things but still no result, just re-install the ubuntu and it will be good, I guess it's a bug

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer found here: https://www.pcspecialist.co.uk/forums/threads/solved-ubuntu-20-04-2-the-touchpad-on-my-initia-15-6-does-not-work-properly.78128/

1. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. comment out the old line and replace with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nocrs"
```

3. `sudo update-grub & reboot`

Finger scrolling should continue to work