# Enable 2 Finger Scrolling | TouchPad not in Settings

Tags: 20.04, touchpad

I've a brand new fancy RGB PC Specialist laptop; which I'm sure would support such a hardware feature.

I've a similar problem to this poster's [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/1357082/1383985). I too cannot see TouchPad within Settings.

Do I need to install anything?

---

Settings:
[image: Screenshot of Settings GUI]

Terminal (machine info.):

```
me@me:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

```
me@me:~$ dmesg | grep pnp; uname -r
[    0.589454] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.593674] pnp 00:00: disabling [io  0x3322-0x3323] because it overlaps 0000:00:1d.0 BAR 13 [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[    0.593752] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.593914] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active)
[    0.593934] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0f13 (active)
[    0.594552] pnp 00:05: disabling [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] because it overlaps 0000:00:02.0 BAR 9 [mem 0x00000000-0xdfffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.596744] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 8 devices
5.11.0-27-generic
```

LMK what other info. I should post.

Comment: Probably this fancy touchpad is not supported by Ubuntu yet.

Comment: Grim ;( How will I know when it is? How do I update to latest Ubuntu easily/ safely?

Comment: First try yo update the system. You have an obsolete kernel. You installed from an old ISO. Then, if it doesn't help, test with Ubuntu 22.04 liveUSB

Answer (score -1):

To enable two-finger scrolling on a touchpad in Ubuntu, you can use the "Synaptics Touchpad" settings found in the "Mouse and Touchpad" settings. If the touchpad settings are not showing up in the settings, you can try the following steps:

Open a terminal window by pressing "Ctrl+Alt+T"
Type the command "sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics" and press Enter
Restart your computer
Go to the settings and navigate to "Mouse and Touchpad" settings, you should now be able to see the Synaptics Touchpad settings.
In the Synaptics Touchpad settings, you should be able to enable two-finger scrolling and configure other touchpad settings as well.
If this method does not work, it could be that your touchpad is not compatible with the Synaptics driver, and you may need to look into alternative drivers or settings.

Comment: Modern Ubuntu releases use `libinput' and also the device should be supported by kernel.